# VR Camera and Hands height

Tags: camera, virtual-reality, oculus

Using the Oculus Rift S, I just added OVRCameraRig and LocalAvatar or OVRPlayerController and when I press play I feel like I'm not as high as I want in my vision and hands, I change the position of Y of objets to make it more higher, but it affects to everything, my guardian setup floor goes more high too and it does not match with my floor. What can I do to solve this? What should I change or modify?

Comment: It sounds like you might not have your floor height calibrated correctly. Try re-running your initial setup where it asks you to enter your height and stand in front of the sensors, and see if you observe any difference in-game afterward. It could also be that the scale of your objects in your scene is a bit too big, which could make you feel small/low to the ground in proportion.

Comment: When I have the prefab in position 0,0,0 the floor match with the guardian setup, I did re doing the initial setup and guardian too, but when I move it more high in Y, the floor does not match with my guardian floor, I have my Tracking Origin type with Floor level too

Comment: That sounds like the expected result. Your prefab position corresponds to the height of your real-world floor. To move it higher, you are raising not just the player's head but also their hands and feet and floor to follow. What do you want / expect to happen instead?

Comment: I re scaled all my prefabs 50% for trying to fix this problem, but in case I want to put my VR camera more high how can I do without moving my guardian setup? That's what I can't do, because when I move my prefab or just the camera, the guardian area moves more high too.

Comment: Think of your guardian setup as your player's feet, and the camera as their head. Trying to move the player's head up without moving their feet is like stretching them on a rack, a medieval torture device. Don't do that to your players! You just build the floor for the player to stand on. It's up to the player's physiology and pose to decide how high up their head sits above that floor at any given moment. That's not an independent variable that you can control without uncomfortably diverging the player's experience from their real environment, risking vertigo or simulation sickness.

Comment: So I should move my ovrcamerarig and localavatar first, then go to oculus and setup everything again, it should fix it?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you think needs to be fixed here. Maybe it would help to illustrate your question with screenshots and diagrams.

Comment: I got it, thank you, so I just needed to scale my objects to a real world size.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please post an answer explaining your solution to help future readers experiencing similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by scaling the game objects that affects to my player, as if it were real life.